# How radial component is positive and negative with respect to the direction in conical pendulum and rotor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion

These are the words from 3rd paragraph of Topic "The Conical Pendulum" in book Halliday Resnink Krane 5th-e
"The radial component is negative if we define the radial direction to be positive outward from the central axis"
What is central axis here. Is it center of bob or center of circle? if center of bob then then it means that we take direction along normal of the tangent to the circle but if center of circle then it is confusing.
Now In the next topic named "Rotor" in second paragraph
the writer says "we define the positive radial direction outward from the axis of rotation". here it has made reference "axis of rotation" mean center of rotor.
My question is "How we will take the direction of radial component or in other words what is the origin of cartesian coordinates (reference point)?
As in conical pendulum the reference is center of bob(in my view) but in rotor the reference is center of axis of rotation
[image: here it is picture of forces direction of both conical pendulum and rotor splitted by white line.]

Comment: In solving any physics problem, the choice of a coordinate system is up to you (unless it's specified in the problem statement).  Choose one that makes the solution as simple as possible, then be sure your equations are consistent with your chosen system.

Comment: The central axis is a vertical line going through the pivot.

Comment: Ive always heard the “precession axis” and the spinner axis or the top’s axis. Never heard central axis. So idk. Logically though, it certainly seems like it makes some sense to call the precession axis the central axis. More importantly, it would just **defy all sense** to call the top’s axis the central axis. That seems implausible. If it were me Id be certain enough thst calling the top’s axis “central” is so silly that Id assume it was not being so labeled. So if me id go w the vertical precession axis

Comment: 2. Are you asking about a rotor, as in a cylinder spinning around one axis. If so, that axis is indeed the centerline yes. And $r=0$ is the axis and any point $r>0$ is $r$ from the centerline, from the axis. If using canonical cylindrical coordinates, then z is the axial dimension. If $z$ is pointing at you, then counterclockwise is positive $\theta$ direction. (Also by the right hand rule)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see Bob in the pendulum problem but I assume he is the sphere attached to the string.

The central axis is clearly that of rotation (the vertical axis). The radial coordinate of Bob is simply defined as the shortest distance between Bob and that axis.

If Bob goes closer to the axis, his change in radial coordinate will be negative.

Comment: If you @fffred dont know the answer then its better not to comment

Comment: I believe I answered your question. Or maybe your question was not clear. I indicated the definition of the radial coordinate you were asking about, and why it can be negative.